# What is this strange artifcact on my inductive element?

Tags: measurement, distortion

I was looking at the Voltage/Current on an old inductive element, without any other components in the loop, and I got this weird artifact. Sadly, the xml file I saved was corrupted, so i had to reconstruct it by hand, but it looked pretty much like the sketch I drew.

All I know about the inductive element is that it's salvaged from some kind of old lamp and there was a little capacitor-symbol printed on it's one end, and a switch-like symbol on the other.

Has anyone seen something like this before, or any good guesses what could cause this?

[image: Weird artifact]

The source is a 12Vpp AC Source plugged straight into the inductor in series with a 1kOhm resistor. The yellow line is current (measured as voltage over the resistor), the blue line is voltage. This is a reconstruction of a two-channel oscilloscope picture, please excuse the lack of labels.

Comment: The graph is not labled and you don't have a schematic, we don't really have a good idea of what your talking about. The load makes a difference when talking about inductors, especially if its variable.

Comment: Sorry. It's a 12Vpp AC Source plugged straight into the inductor in series with a 1kOhm resistor. The yellow line is current (measured as voltage over the resistor), the blue line is voltage. I don't know how big the inductance is, but it has an internal resistance of 38 Ohm. The Frequency is at 60Hz here.

Comment: The voltage leads the current by 90 deg, so it looks like an inductor.

Comment: @Chu yes, it's an inductor. It's that little notch at every voltage peak which I am interested in.

Comment: It could be from hysteresis in the magnetics (ferrite core) or the load (which could be a triac or a rectifier).

Comment: @laptop2d wouldn't hysteresis effects be visible on both sides, symmetric around the peak, not just one?

Comment: Don't know, I can't see your circuit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know exactly what that is. Its a ring in the transformer caused from the center tapped not in the center, this causes a little bump, but if you magnify it, you will see a decaying ring at the spike. I'll snap a picture of one here once I get back at the house.

Comment: oh that sounds very plausible! Do you know why that ring exists if you run it off-center?

Comment: I think it has to do with winding overlap, or when they tied the two parts of the coil together: that soldering has resistance (like a cold joint).